# Create a page in Confluence using ScriptRunner

Tags: confluence

I'm working for a company that it has Jira Cloud, and we need to create some Confluence page since a Jira flow using script runner, is this possible?, and if its possible how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Yes, you can use Confluence REST API to create a page in Confluence from JIRA with Script Runner. There are couple of examples like [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Atlassian-Marketplace-questions/How-to-automatically-create-a-Confluence-Page-on-Jira-Issue/qaq-p/300772) in Atlassian Community that you can take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have another question, how can I authenticate this Confluence Page?   Thank you again

Comment: Take a look at REST API Examples : https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples